# Как обратиться к элементу EditText созданным программно

Tags: android, android-edittext

Краткая суть: пользователь нажимает на кнопку, добавляется новый EditText - и так до бесконечности.
Установить ID к создаваемым EditText я смог, но теперь мне нужно считать данные из EditText и поместить их в массив. 
Основная проблема заключаются в том, что я не знаю, как обратиться к ID динамического объекта и считать введённый текст. Подскажите, что делать.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            //count = 1
            editText.setId(count);

            // Проверка того, что ID создан и установка его в качестве текста
            int s = editText.getId();
            String name = String.valueOf(s);
            editText.setText(name);
            // Конец проверки

            layout.addView(editText, layoutParams);
            count++;
```

Код находится в OnClick.

Comment: А что будет если приложение свернут и система очистит активную память приложения? Все данные по новой вбивать? Смотрите сразу в сторону списков (например `RecyclerView`) и хранения данных (например в БД).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте каждый созданный Edittext записывать в массив EditText[ ] а потом обращаться через индекс
your_array[0].gettext();

Если надо найти edittext с конкретными id можно пройтись циклом по масиву.

Answer (score 0):

1. Для генерации лучше использовать ViewCompat.generateViewId(), если сами будете генерить, можете поймать исключение.
2. Проще всего сразу после генерации помещать их в список, потом фильтровать и тд. и т.п

Comment: Да, я читал об автоматической генерации ID с помощью generateViewId(), но Ваш ответ не принёс мне пользы.